# Running Nginx in pod without privilege escalation

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx, security-context

I'm trying to get Nginx to run with minimal privileges while being able to act as a proxy on port 80. In other words, this is the securityContext I'm working with:

```yaml
            securityContext:
              allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
              readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
              runAsNonRoot: true
              runAsUser: 12321
              runAsGroup: 12321
              privileged: false
              capabilities:
                drop:
                - all
                add: ["NET_BIND_SERVICE"]
```

From what I can gather most stackoverflow questions around this subject set `allowPrivilegeEscalation` to `true`. Other than that I have found [this blog from Bridcrew](https://bridgecrew.io/blog/creating-a-secure-kubernetes-nginx-deployment-using-checkov/) that set it to `false` but I can't reproduce their example on my end.

I also tried to use the `nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged` base image but also with no luck.

---

Here's my Dockerfile. It consists of a lot of `chown` and `chmod`ing, but I also install libcap2 so I can set the `NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability and move some files around for a custom entrypoint.

```
FROM nginx

ENV NGINX_USER="proxy-user" \
    NGINXR_UID="12321" \
    NGINX_GROUP="proxy-group" \
    NGINX_GID="12321"  

RUN set -ex; \
  groupadd -r --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_GROUP"; \
  useradd -r --uid "$NGINXR_UID" --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_USER" 


# Create empty pid file and assign it to the proxy user
RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
    chown -R proxy-user:proxy-group /var/run/nginx.pid

# Change permissions of other nginx files
RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/nginx && \
    chown -R proxy-user:proxy-group /usr/share/nginx/html && \
    chown -R proxy-user:proxy-group /var/cache/nginx && \
    chown -R proxy-user:proxy-group /var/log/nginx && \
    chown -R proxy-user:proxy-group /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Install libcap and set the NET_BIND_SERVICE capability to the Nginx binary
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -qq install --no-install-recommends libcap2-bin -y && \
    setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=ep /usr/sbin/nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf.template /etc/nginx/templates/

# Move all nginx files to another directory. We will later mount a writable directory under /etc/nginx/ and copy these files back  before launching Nginx
RUN mv /etc/nginx /etc/nginx-defaults

# This file does the copying and launches nginx (via docker-entrypoint.sh)
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
USER proxy-user

ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh
```

As mentioned in the comments we will mount a couple of writable emptydir directories Nginx can use:

```yaml
            volumeMounts:
              - name: nginx-etc
                mountPath: /etc/nginx
              - name: nginx-cache
                mountPath: /var/cache/nginx
              - name: nginx-tmp
                mountPath: /tmp/nginx
              - name: nginx-pid
                mountPath: /var/run
```

And in the nginx.conf a couple of paths to point to these directories in case they weren't already the default value:

```
http {
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx/proxy_temp;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx/client_temp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/nginx/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/nginx/scgi_temp;

    ...
}
```

And here is the custom entrypoint

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running from custom entrypoint"

# Move the nginx files back to the default directory
cp -a /etc/nginx-defaults/. /etc/nginx/

# Launch nginx through the docker entrypoint
./docker-entrypoint.sh nginx
```

The error I'm getting is that it can't bind to port 80 due to permission denied:

```
2023/03/31 12:31:03 [emerg] 11#11: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Setting `allowPrivilegeEscalation` to `true` fixes the issue. As well as binding to a non privileged port (>1024), but is there a way to work around the privilege escalation issue without having to bind to a higher port?

---

Edit, on request the yaml of an entire pod to work with. This example uses the unmodified nginx image which also tries to bind to port 80 and shows the bind error.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  containers:
    - name: proxy
      image: nginx
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-cache
          mountPath: /var/cache/nginx
        - name: nginx-tmp
          mountPath: /tmp/nginx
        - name: nginx-pid
          mountPath: /var/run
      securityContext:
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 12321
        runAsGroup: 12321
        privileged: false
        capabilities:
          drop:
          - all
          add: ["NET_BIND_SERVICE"]
  volumes:
  - name: nginx-cache
    emptyDir:
      sizeLimit: 1Mi
  - name: nginx-tmp
    emptyDir:
      sizeLimit: 1Mi
  - name: nginx-pid
    emptyDir:
      sizeLimit: 1Mi
```

Comment: I think you need more info to proceed. Can you get into the container and find `/var/log/syslog`? There might be some info there. Also, there might be some information inside nginx's `error.log`.

Comment: `error.log` points to stderr which gets picked up automatically by `kubectl logs` so this is all that is logged. Even with debug logging there's one more line that doesn't tell anything new: `2023/04/03 09:17:04 [debug] 11#11: bind() 0.0.0.0:80 #6`

Comment: Not that familiar with kubernetes - can't you enter into a container like you can in docker? Pretty sure you'd find some extra info on error 13 in syslog.

Comment: Yes, just like in Docker you can enter a container. Anyway, `/var/log/syslog` doesn't exist.

Comment: Mind sharing a working .yaml file to deploy the container?

Comment: I've added the yaml of an unmodified nginx pod with the security context and mounted directories so it results in the same bind error.